# Register file in vhdl without case statements

Tags: vhdl

Can you help me with describing the scheme in vhdl? I want to write a 1kByte register file. It consists of decoder (10-to-1024) for writing, 1024 registers, multiplexer (1024-to-1) for reading.

I know only how to implement MUX like this: `m(0) <= (not s and x(0)) or (s and y(0));` or using case statement. But using 1024 case statements is a very bad solution. Thus, how to describe it in vhdl without cases?

Comment: See IEEE 1076-2008 8.4 Indexed names.  For your register file imagine `type regf is array(0 to 1023) of std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);' signal regfile: regf; signal readaddr: std_logic_vector (9 downto 0);signal some_signal: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);`.  A read multiplexer could be described by `some_signal <= regfile(to_integer(unsigned(readaddr)));` where the integer value of the binary representing array value of readaddr indexes (selects) an element of regifile.  You might benefit from reading up on or taking a course in VHDL and synthesis. (`use ieee.numeric_std.all;`)

Comment: @user1155120 Thanks! And what about decoder? Can I also implement it like this?

Comment: You additional question isn't clear without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or more detail.

Comment: If you mean how do you select a location to write too in your register file, use an indexed name as the target of an assignment statement.

Comment: @user1155120 ok, don't answer it. About mux, why `std_logic_vector (31 downto 0)` not `std_logic_vector (9 downto 0)`? We need 10 bits for choosing from 1024 inputs

Comment: @user1155120 Yes, you understood me right.

Comment: `readaddr: std_logic_vector (9 downto 0);` is the read address the selection of one of 1024 locations from regfile is `regfile(to_integer(unsigned(readaddr)))` usind an indexed name.

Comment: @user1155120 Ok, you mean 32 bit numbers? It's my mistake, I didn't write that I use 8bit 2's complement numbers. So, I need `(7 downto 0)`, right?

Comment: @user1155120 why not make this an answer?